# What determines package names in bitbake

Tags: linux, cmake, yocto, bitbake

I noticed that for my build 4 packages are placed into deploy/rpm, a normal, debug, dev, and src. But what determines the actual name for those 4 packages. I noticed the name changed when I used cmake to set the version of my build, but I don't exactly know how bitbake determines that.

Answer (score 1):

This is defined by Yocto's classes, you can find them in [`meta/classes`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/classes?h=dunfell).

For example, the `-dev` and the `-dbg` packages are added by an anonymous python function in [`packagegroup.bbclass`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/classes/packagegroup.bbclass?h=dunfell#n25):

```py
# This automatically adds -dbg and -dev flavours of all PACKAGES
# to the list. Their dependencies (RRECOMMENDS) are handled as usual
# by package_depchains in a following step.
# Also mark all packages as ALLOW_EMPTY
python () {
    packages = d.getVar('PACKAGES').split()
    if d.getVar('PACKAGEGROUP_DISABLE_COMPLEMENTARY') != '1':
        types = ['', '-dbg', '-dev']
        if bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'ptest', True, False, d):
            types.append('-ptest')
        packages = [pkg + suffix for pkg in packages
                    for suffix in types]
        d.setVar('PACKAGES', ' '.join(packages))
    for pkg in packages:
        d.setVar('ALLOW_EMPTY_%s' % pkg, '1')
}
```

You can also find information on the PACKAGE variable [in the manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-PACKAGES).